# How To Save text in Textbox

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm kind of a beginner in coding I've been doing it for a couple of months doing basic things. I'd like to know how to make a basic account sign in type of thing, where you type in your username and password that you want press submit then it saves those to the html file and remember it when I exit and that the next time you type in your username and password it will recognize the username and password. Any thoughts? The code I have so far...

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sign Up!!!</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name="UserName" value="Username">
<br>
<input type="text" name="Password" value=Password">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="SU" value="Sign Up" onclick="su()"
</form>
<script>
function su(){
var su = document.getElementsByName("Username")[0].value;
var su2 = document.getElementsByName("Password")[0].value;
          
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the var su to get what's in the text boxes, but I'm not sure on how to save those two things. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do that, but there are very simple way in HTML5, just put `<input type="text">` for the user name and `<input type="password">` and the web browser will automatically cache it.

Comment: I looked at your post in the edit and It didn't show the input types you picked, but thank you I will look into that.

Answer (score -1):

There are many youtube tutorials for your answers. However, you will mainly need php. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kltXTKjcQ-0) is a link to a tutorial about register and login.

Comment: Do you possibly have a non youtube link as well?